# CSS3 method for defining specific site contents/sections

Tags: html, css, validation, syntax

What's the best and correct way to identify specific sections or contents inside a CSS3 stylesheet.

For example, if I have an image syntax defined like this for all images:

```
/* Image */

    .image {
        border: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }
```

And now I want to define different settings for the images inside a specific section, for example here:

```
<!-- One -->
        <section id="one" class="wrapper major-pad">
```

What's the correct way to do it? Using the **Section ID** or the **Class** in the CSS syntax? (please inform the correct syntax I should use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have many sections with same class but want to target an image in a specific one, use id

```
#one .image { ... }
```

If you want to target an image within a section with a given class, use class

```
.wrapper.major-pad .image { ... }
```

or

```
.wrapper .image { ... }
```

or

```
.major-pad .image { ... }
```

---

Updated based on a comment, showing a simple sample

```css
.wrapper .image {
  border: 5px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<section id="one" class="wrapper major-pad">
  <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/300x100/"> 
</section>
```

Comment: what shall I put inside the { ... }?
Sorry but I'm a newbie in CSS.